# recv() socket loop never end C

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

A am writing a client-server program in C. It sends a directory name and receives a list of files as answer. The problem I have is that it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

If I send only one directory name it works, but if I send a list of directories it never ends and outputs nothing.

### Server

```
while(recv(sock, name, BUFSIZE, 0) > 0){
    if ((fddir=opendir(name)) == NULL){
        send(sock, strerror(errno), strlen(strerror(errno)), 0);
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }
    send(sock, name, strlen(name), 0);
    send(sock, ":", strlen(":"), 0);
    send(sock, "\n", strlen("\n"), 0);
    while ((dirbuf = readdir(fddir)) != NULL){
        buf[0] = '\0';
        strcat(buf, dirbuf->d_name);
        strcat(buf, "\t");
        send(sock, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
    }
}
```

### Client

```
for (int i=1;i<3;i++){
    send(sock, argv[i], strlen(path), 0);
    while(recv(sock, buf, BUFSIZE, 0) > 0)
        printf("%s", buf);
}
```

The server waits until all directory names are received, and then the client wait until server send all files in it. How do I trace where the program gets stuck?

Comment: And the error is ...?

Comment: No errors,nothing,only loop that output nothing

Comment: @NatKup how do you know there are no errors? you're not checking for them.

Comment: Using send(sock, argv[i], strlen(argv[i]), 0); in client sounds better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is not message based, so you have no way of knowing where the boundaries between two client `send()` calls is when you call `recv()` on the server.  Thus when you send multiple names back-to-back it is possible for the server to receive them all in a single `recv()` (or however many bytes you allocated for `BUFSIZE`).  This is probably mangling your directory names, causing `opendir` to fail.  This would be more obvious to you if you were checking for errors from `send` and `recv` and Captain Obvlious describes in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the calls to [`recv`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) for errors. It returns 0 if the connection was disconnected and -1 on an error. You are only checking for values `> 0` which will not work. The example below shows how to approach checking the errors.

```
while(true)
{
    const int result = recv(sock, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);l
    if(result == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << errno << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    else if(result == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Disconnected" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    //  process the data here. No errors
}
```

You should also be checking the value returned by [`send`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send) as it works in the same way.